# Get the order of selection from an IStructuredSelection

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface

I wrote an Eclipse plugin which allows the user to compare SLOC counts between two projects. The plugin is kicked off simply by highlighting two projects in the Project Explorer View, right clicking, and selecting the plugin (the plugin is launched via the context menu). The plugin always compares ProjectA to ProjectB regardless of the order ProjectA and ProjectB were selected. I would like to use the order of selection to determine if the user will get a comparison of ProjectA to ProjectB or ProjectB to ProjectA.

Given an `IStructuredSelection`, how can I tell which project was selected first?

BTW - It seems that `getFirstElement()` does not give you the first element selected, just the first element in the list (which, again, is not necessarily the first element [Project in this case] selected)

Comment: I really don't think that's possible. The `IStructuredSelection` doesn't "know" the order in which the items were selected, only which ones are currently selected.

Comment: Baz - is there anyway to get the order that it was selected? Could I get it off the `ExecutionEvent` or use the `HandlerUtil` to get it somehow?

Comment: I don't know any method. Check the Javadoc. Can't you just use the Project on which the right-click occurred as the first one?

Comment: @Baz, I don't know how to capture the first click otherwise I would be able to easily know the click order - any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you use the first click, but you can determine the item on which the right click occurred (i.e. the source of the event). Then you can at least guess that this was the second click.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the order of selection from the IStructuredSelection, but there is another option.  For menu/popup actions you get the current selections by having a selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection) method.  This method is called whenever the selection changes.  Normally you throw out the last selection and just keep the new IStructuredSelection, but if you compare the previous IStructuredSelection to the one that's been passed to you you'll see what's been added and removed since the last selection action.  By tracking these changes over time you should be able to know the order of selection.

Comment: Chris - thanks for the tip. Unfortunately the `selectionChanged()` method is only entered after I have already selected the second project and started the plugin run. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in there to confirm?  It should also be called when you make the first selection, unless you use a drag motion to select both at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, I used the break point to confirm. I think it is because my public class for the plugin implements `IObjectActionDelegate` such that the `selectionChanged` is only detecting changes regarding the plugin and not the project (so when I click on the plugin to run it sees that as a "selection change" but not when I click on the project) . . .

Answer (score 0):

You simply should not make this depending on the order of selection events. As a user, I would be very angry, if I not only have to choose 2 projects, but must click them in the right order to get the result I want.

Instead, put a button or other UI element into your results view to "switch comparison order". That's way more easy to understand and remember for users.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Banaeweizen, but this plugin is for a very small team of users who are instructed very specifically on how to use it.